# Show that $X$ is Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be the interval $\lbrack 0,1 \rbrack$ and let $\beta$ be the collection of all the following subsets of $X$: all open intervals $(a,b) \subset \lbrack 0,1\rbrack$ and all subsets of the form $\lbrack0,a) \cup (b,1 \rbrack$.

i)Show that $\beta$ is a basis for a topology on $X$.

ii)Give $X$ the topology determined by the basis in part i).Determine whether or not $X$ has the Hausdorff property.

My attempt:

i) Let $x \in \lbrack 0,1\rbrack$. Then $x \in (\frac{x}{2},\frac{x+1}{2}) \in \beta $. Suppose $\beta_1,\beta_2 \in \beta$ and $x \in \beta_1 \cap \beta_2$. Aim: Show that there is a basis element $\beta_3$ such that $\beta_3 \subset \beta_1 \cap \beta_2$. I stuck at this part. I don know how to deal with the open intervals which have two forms.

ii)Graphically, I think is yes. Because for any two distinct points in $\lbrack 0,1 \rbrack $, we can always find open intervals which have empty intersection. But I don know how to write it in mathematical form.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: The second topology is not Hausdorff because only open neighbourhoods of $x=1$ is $[0,1]$.

Comment: @user52045 why isn't $[0,a)\cup(b,1]$ an open neighborhood of $1$ (when $a < b$)?

Comment: Sorry i thought that in point 2 we take obly open sets of the form $(a,b)$.

Comment: @user52045 I agree that it won't be Hausdorff though. But, I think the point is that if $x=0$ and $y=1$, then any open neighborhood of $x$ will also be one for $y$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** For i) Can you convince yourself that if $\beta_1, \beta_2 \in \beta$, then either $\beta_1 \cap \beta_2 \in \beta$ or there exists two disjoint open intervals $\alpha, \gamma \in \beta$ such that $\alpha \cup \gamma = \beta_1 \cap \beta_2$ (I suppose if you don't consider $\varnothing$ to be an interval, you should specify any two non-disjoint $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$). Then if $x \in \beta_1 \cap \beta_2$, perhaps $\beta_3 = \beta_1 \cap \beta_2$ in the first case, or for the second case $\beta_3 = \alpha$ if $x \in \alpha$ or $\beta_3 = \gamma$ if $x \in \gamma$.

For ii) If $x \neq y$ and $x, y \in (0,1)$ then there should be some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\beta_x = (x-1/n,x+1/n)$ and $\beta_y = (y-1/n,y+1/n)$ should be disjoint (think Archimedean property of $\mathbb{R}$). But, what if $x = 0$ and $y=1$.. can you find open sets containing $x$ and $y$ which are disjoint?

Can you take it from here?

Comment: If you want to observe that $X\setminus\{0,1\}$ is Hausdorff, it’s easier just to note that it inherits the same topology from $X$ that it does from $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott You're absolutely right (per usual). I've edited for a fix.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I agree that restricted to $(0,1)$ the topology is inherited from that on $\mathbb{R}$, I just wasn't sure if he was allowed to "know" that $\mathbb{R}$ is Hausdorff at this point.. I also  don't think it was necessary to mention the Hausdorff property of $X \backslash\{0,1\}$, but maybe instructive to show how we might show it if it arises later.

Comment: I figured that that was why you did it; I just thought that it was worth mentioning the easy way in case it is available. (I keep wanting to paste $0$ and $1$ back together to restore $S^1$!)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Definitely worth pointing out and very instructive to mention both methods. $S^1$ indeed... but the rubberband is unfortunately cut!

Comment: So from the question, we know that $a \neq 0$ and $b \neq 1$?

Comment: @Idonknow I'm not sure whether the question would allow you to consider $a=0$ and/or $b=1$. If you *are* allowed to take $a=0$ or $b=1$, then similar to Brian's point, you will be left with the interval $X$ having the induced topology from $\mathbb{R}$. However, if you're not allowed to take $a=0$ or $b=1$, then you won't be able to find disjoint open sets separating the point $0$ and $1$, forcing $X$ to be non-Hausdorff. So, your question is good and valid and certainly leaves room open for different answers. I'm not sure what the author of the question intended.